# Difference between [a,b] and [a][b]

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm using pytorch and have the following case:

- A is a nxm matrix filled with zeros
- b is a normal list of k indices smaller than n
- c is a single integer smaller than m

I now wanted to do `A[b, c] += 1` and first implemented it as `A[b][c] += 1`.
The issue is that I got the result I wanted with `A[b, c] += 1`, where as `A[b][c] += 1` kept the matrix to full zeros.

I was wondering why that is the case, as I would have expected both commands to do the same operation. I would greatly appreciate your thoughts on this :)

kind regards,
Felix

**Code**:

```py
A = torch.zeros((100, 20))
b = [2, 3, 4]
c = 2

# empty
A[b][c] += 1
print(A) 

# works
A[b,c] += 1
print(A)
```

Comment: What you say matrix, do you mean an actual `matrix` instance, an `ndarray`, or something else entirely? (i.e. please [show the code you're using](/help/how-to-ask) in addition to your description)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, its an torch.Tensor object, see the code in the edit. And thank you for your time :)

Comment: `A[b][c]+=...` is two separate indexing operations..  In effect, `temp=A[b[` and `temp[c]+=...`.  You have understand what each step does.  `A[b,c]+=` is one step.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at their shapes:

```
>>> A[b][c].shape
torch.Size([20])
>>> A[b,c].shape
torch.Size([3])
```

`A[b][c]` and `A[b,c]` only mean the same thing when `b` and `c` are scalar. When `b` is a list, you're selecting entire *rows* of `A` using `A[b]`, and then indexing those rows with `A[b][c]`.

You'll see that `A[b].shape` is `(3, 20)` here, so you've selected 3 rows, and then `A[b][c]` gets the 3rd row. In fact, the only reason that your code doesn't crash was because it happened to be the case that `c < len(b)`.  Try it with `c = 5` and you'll get an `IndexError` with `A[b][c]`, but `A[b,c]` is still valid.