# Numpy assignment on *1D* chained indices like `arr[mask][range:]`

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, variable-assignment

As an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), let's say I have an array of numbers `arr`. I then want to extract certain elements from `arr` (based on a boolean mask), and set only the first `n` of those extracted elements to zero.

I'd expect to be able to do this:

```py
import numpy as np
# Just an example array of numbers [20, 21, ..., 40]
arr = np.linspace(20, 40, 21)
# A mask selecting all numbers less than 25
mask = arr < 25
# As an example, only take the first 5 values
n = 5
# Attempt to set the first `n` values matching the `mask` to zero
arr[mask][:n] = 0

# It doesn't work
print(arr)
# array([20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32.,
#      33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39., 40.])
```

It doesn't work, none of the values have been set to zero. I'm guessing this is related/similar to the [pandas chained indices and assignment issue](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

In this particular example, it's easy-ish to get around the problem with `np.nonzero`:

```py
indices = np.nonzero(mask)[0]
arr[indices[:n]] = 0
print(arr)
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32.,
#      33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39., 40.])
```

But I couldn't actually find anything about numpy not allowing/not working with chained indices and assignments, so I wanted to see if there was a better way? Or if I was making a mistake and these sorts of chained-indices-and-assignments are actually possible.

Comment: `arr[mask]` is a copy of `arr`.  You change that, not `arr` itself.  Just a few days ago some asked about `x[a][b]` versus `x[a,b]`.  Each `[]` is a separate indexing operation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980613/difference-between-a-b-and-ab - not an exact duplicate, but the underlying issues are similar

Comment: There is *plenty* of written about the semantics of numpy indexing, definitely, you should at least look at the [official user guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)